# Set REG_NONE value via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\OpenWithProgids -Name Paint.Picture -Type None -Value ([byte[]]::new(0)) -Force
```

works in Windows 10, but there is an issue in Windows 8.1.

Comment: Note that the accepted answer creates (empty) `REG_BINARY` registry values, not  `REG_NONE` ones. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685989/45375) to a closely related question uses P/Invoke techniques via `Add-Type` to create true `REG_NONE` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `new` static extension method for invoking constructors is new in PowerShell 5.0, the version of Windows PowerShell that ships with Windows 10.

In Windows PowerShell 4.0, the version that ships with 8.1, you should be able to attain the same kind of empty byte array by simply casting an empty array to `byte[]`, like so: `[byte[]]@()`.

The previous version of `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]` does not have a `None` value, but specifying `Unknown` with a `[byte[]]` object as the value will result in the same type of registry value entry - so a version that works on both platforms would be:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.bmp\OpenWithProgids -Name Paint.Picture -Type Unknown -Value ([byte[]]@()) -Force
```