# RegistryValueKind NONE

Tags: powershell, registry, powershell-2.0

How can I set a none data type.`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::None`  in Powershell 2.0?
Powershell 2.0 has types `"Unknown, String, ExpandString, Binary, DWord, MultiString, QWord"`.
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=netframework-3.5)

Comment: Can you provide some context? By none, do you mean have a typeless value?

Comment: Yep, Reg_NONE type.
None -1 
No data type.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind?view=netframework-4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Security.Principal;
    using Microsoft.Win32;
    using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
    namespace AdvapiSolution
    {
        public class Advapi
        {
            public enum HKEY : uint
            {
                HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000,
                HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001,
                HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002,
                HKEY_USERS = 0x80000003,
                HKEY_PERFORMANCE_DATA = 0x80000004,
                HKEY_PERFORMANCE_TEXT = 0x80000050,
                HKEY_PERFORMANCE_NLSTEXT = 0x80000060,
                HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = 0x80000005
            }
            
            private enum VALUE_TYPE : uint
            {
                REG_NONE= 0,
                REG_SZ = 1,
                REG_EXPAND_SZ = 2,
                REG_BINARY = 3,
                REG_DWORD = 4,
                REG_DWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 4,
                REG_DWORD_BIG_ENDIAN = 5,
                REG_LINK = 6,
                REG_MULTI_SZ = 7,
                REG_RESOURCE_LIST = 8,
                REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR = 9,
                REG_RESOURCE_REQUIREMENTS_LIST = 10,
                REG_QWORD_LITTLE_ENDIAN = 11
            }

            [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, BestFitMapping = false)]
            private static extern int RegSetKeyValueW  (
            HKEY hkey, 
            string lpSubKey,
            string lpValueName,
            VALUE_TYPE type, 
            byte[] data, 
            uint dataLength);
            public int set_key(HKEY hkey, string subkey, string valuename){
                return RegSetKeyValueW(hkey, subkey, valuename, VALUE_TYPE.REG_NONE, null, 0);
            }
       }
}
"@
```

In my case data equals `null` and type is `REG_NONE`. You can change `set_key` as you like with object:

```
$Advapiobject = New-Object 'AdvapiSolution.Advapi'
$Advapiobject.set_key('HKEY_CURRENT_USER',$yoursubkey, $yourvaluename, 'REG_NONE')
```

Another way is using a static method `set_key`.
Change `set_key` to `public static int set_key`:

`[AdvapiSolution.Advapi]::set_key('HKEY_CURRENT_USER',$yoursubkey, $yourvaluename, 'REG_NONE')`.

> If it returns `0`, it's okay. If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code defined in `Winerror.h`.

[System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Answer (score 2):

(As implied in your question), [`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::None`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind) (which translates to a `REG_NONE` registry value) requires at least .NET Framework 4, whereas Windows PowerShell v2 is built on .NET Framework 2. (Only Windows PowerShell v3 and above are built on .NET Framework 4 and above).

Unlike C#, PowerShell does *not* allow you to pass the *numerical* value of an `enum`-typed parameter if that value doesn't represent an officially defined member of that enumeration (at that time, in the underlying framework), so attempting to pass `(-1)`, the value of `[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::None`, does *not* work in Windows PowerShell v2 - neither with `New-ItemProperty` / `Set-ItemProperty`'s `-Type` parameter, nor with .NET API calls (`[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue(...)`).

Therefore, **in Windows PowerShell v2, calling the Windows API via P/Invoke declarations implemented via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type) is probably your only option** - see the [`RegSetKeyValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluew) WinAPI function (among others).

**Building on [your own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70685989/45375)**, here's a streamlined solution, which:

- uses [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type)'s `-MemberDefinition` parameter to simplify creation of types that wrap P/Invoke calls.
- Exposes a static `[WinApiHelper.Registry]::SetNoneValue()` method, which:

  - focuses *only* on creating `REG_NONE` values
  - also supports creating such values with byte data (`[byte[]]` arrays)
  - has no return value, but throws a `Win32Exception` should an error occur.

```
Add-Type -Namespace WinApiHelper -Name Registry -MemberDefinition @'
    public enum HKEY : uint
    {
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = 0x80000000,
        HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = 0x80000005,
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER = 0x80000001,
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = 0x80000002,
        HKEY_USERS = 0x80000003
    }
    
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int RegSetKeyValue(
      HKEY hkey, 
      string lpSubKey,
      string lpValueName,
      UInt32 type, 
      byte[] data, 
      UInt32 dataLength
    );

    public static void SetNoneValue(HKEY hkey, string subkey, string valuename, byte[] bytes)
    {
      int rc = RegSetKeyValue(hkey, subkey, valuename, 0 /* REG_NONE */, bytes, (UInt32) (bytes == null ? 0 : bytes.Length));
      if (rc != 0) {
        // Access the error code in PowerShell with $Error[0].Exception.InnerException.NativeErrorCode
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(rc);
      }
    }

    // Overload that creates an empty value.
    // Note: .NET 2 doesn't support optional parameters, so an explicit overload is required.
    public static void SetNoneValue(HKEY hkey, string subkey, string valuename) {
      SetNoneValue(hkey, subkey, valuename, null);
    }

'@
```

**Sample calls:**

```sh
# Create an empty REG_NONE value named 'bar1' in key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\foo.
[WinApiHelper.Registry]::SetNoneValue('HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'foo', 'bar1')

# Create a REG_NONE value named 'bar2' with a byte array.
[WinApiHelper.Registry]::SetNoneValue('HKEY_CURRENT_USER', 'foo', 'bar2', [byte[]] (42, 43))
```